# Magento 2 adding html block to sales_order_grid

Tags: magento2

I try to add a custom HTML block to the admin order grid just above or below the row with [Create New Order] like here:
[image: Magento 2 order view]

http://prntscr.com/nygenr

by overwriting Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <settings>
            <block name="OrderSummary" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\OrderSummary" /></block>
        </settings>
    </listing>
```

I would like to add something like we already got on Magento 1:
[image]

Appreciate with any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the answer in below link.

http://easyndfaster.com/blog/post/magento-2-adding-phtml-block-to-sales_order_grid/

I hope it's useful for you.